# Travel to UK with German refugee passport (blue)

Tags: visas, uk, refugees

With Germany's blue passport issued for refugees, do I need visa to travel to UK? In a website www.handbookgermany.de they have mentioned that I can travel visa free to European countries as well as countries member of European Council.... UK is also a member of EU council. Still I need to confirm before travel.

Comment: Note that the agreement about visa-free travel for refugees is not the work of the [**European Council**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Council), but of the [**Council of Europe**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_Europe), which is a _completely different thing_. The European Council is one of the policy-making bodies of the EU; the Council of Europe is a separate international organization whose members include countries both within and without the EU. (And the [Council of the European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_the_European_Union) is different still).

Answer (score 4):

[The "Reiseausweis"](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Konventionspass_Deutschland.png)?

No, you cannot enter the UK without a visa with that document, because the UK (France too) has opted out of that regulation at the moment. **The UK requires you to have a visa.** (France at the moment does not require you to have a visa, although they opted out, too.)